# Blank Pink Screen after Choosing User in Ubuntu 20.04 after Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

After running `sudo apt upgrade` and restarting, I would not be able to enter my password after choosing the user in the login manager. I would just be greeted by a blank pink screen.  I would be able to go into the gui after timeshift restore, but find it very annoying that everytime my firefox profiles and my pip packages would just be lost.  I have tried multiple methods, which include changing my nvidia driver to nouveau drivers, rolling down the kernel version, or going into recovery mode to boot.  None of these would work.  I have currently held the kernel from updating, though I would wish to receive the newest most secure updates.  I am out of my wits and would be beyond grateful if someone can help me with my problem

Edit: It appears that I am able to login with a test user. But most of my files are on my previous user profile, and I do not at all want to switch users.

Comment: Please post the hardware specifications.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 7570, bought around 2016, with Intel UHD 620, NVIDIA MX130, 8 GB of RAM, laptop with touchscreen, CPU is the Intel Core i7-8550U @ 1.8 GHZ.  Is there any specific specifications you want?

Answer (score 1):

It was a corrupted install of howdy that interfered with user login causing the failure to login to my user.  I found this issue after trying another test user and it was successful.